# animations on angular-dart 0.11

Tags: dart, angular-dart

OK, I'm on angular-dart 0.11.0, following the examples provided, applying the appropriate name changes and no joy. Here goes:

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';
import 'package:angular/animate/module.dart';

part 'package:myapp/src/my_ctrl.dart';
part 'package:myapp/src/my_dir.dart';


class MyModule extends Module {
  MyModule() {
    install(new AnimationModule());
    bind(MyCtrl);
    bind(MyDir);
  }
}

main() {
  applicationFactory()
    .addModule(new MyModule())
    .run();
}
```

main.css

```css
.my-base-class.ng-enter {
  transition: all 2s;
  opacity: 0.000001; /* to avoid some chrome bug? */
}
.my-base-class.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

index.html

```dart
<div ng-if="ctrl.bool" class="my-base-class">my stubbornly refusing to animate content</div>
```

the animation related classes ('ng-enter', etc) don't seem to get applied. Instead, i see an 'ng-binding' class. I suspect that the current code doesn't even activate the animation feature but i don't know how to fix it as there are no error messages.

thanks in advance

Comment: This [demo](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/example/web/animation/visibility_demo.dart) seems very similar.
I can't see a flaw in your code but I have to admit that I haven't used NgAnimate myself yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it out, there was nothing wrong with the animation setup. The problem was on how I was initiating the animation. I was expecting some data from an ajax call and, of course, angular-dart cannot handle this on its own, it needs to be told about the change through 'scope.watch'